# Changing datasource of UITableView using a UISegmentedControl (Like Twitter does)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to create a Table View in which the data source can be changed depending on which Index is selected on the UISegmentedControl. I will post what I have. It doesnt seem to be working! I want to do it like Twitter does on their profile page with the "Tweets, Media Favourites" segmented Controller.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    switch (self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            return 10;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 15;
            break;
        case 2:
            return 5;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 30;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    self.segmentedControliPhone4 = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"ACTIVITY FEED", @"HOT BOX", @"COLLECTIONS"]];
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.frame = CGRectMake(0, 263, self.view.frame.size.width, 30);
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationDown;
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleBox;
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato" size:10];
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.016 green:0.850 blue:0.796 alpha:1];
    self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.016 green:0.850 blue:0.796 alpha:1];
    [self.segmentedControliPhone4 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return self.segmentedControliPhone4;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    switch (self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Acitivy Feed";
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brand.png"];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Hot Box";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Collections";
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(HMSegmentedControl *)segmentedControl{

    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        self.hotBoxTableView.hidden = NO;
        [self.hotBoxTableView reloadData];
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        self.hotBoxTableView.hidden = NO;
        [self.hotBoxTableView reloadData];
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
        self.hotBoxTableView.hidden = NO;
        [self.hotBoxTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I am using a Custom Segmented COntrol, but willing to change to the Regular one. If you have any insight or questions, please let me know!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What isn't working?  Also, the title of your question contains a good design idea:  you can actually change a tableview's datasource by changing its datasource property.

Comment: The Segmented control doesnt change values (It keeps one highlighted all the time) and also the data inside the tableview is crossed with the one highlighted and with the index that you select manually. So its trying to display two datasources.

Comment: 1- I would probably start by fixing the control. If the thing controlling the table view is broken, then address that before worrying about the table itself. 2- I'm guessing that your table view "crossed" data is due to you not resetting the image in the event that index 1 or 2 is selected. Is the number of cells properly updating when you choose a new index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First you should clear the data before you updated the cells

```
cell.textLabel.text = nil
cell.imageView.image = nil
switch (self.segmentedControliPhone4.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Acitivy Feed";
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brand.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Hot Box";
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Collections";
        break;
}
```

Second, in segmentedControlIndexChanged you are running same code in different if statements. The following should do enough

```
-(void)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(HMSegmentedControl *)segmentedControl{

    self.hotBoxTableView.hidden = NO;
    [self.hotBoxTableView reloadData];
```

}